# Certain build triggers build run a different build script in TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, automated-tests

Is there anyway to run certain build triggers and thus run different build steps? Or would I have to seperate out the different projects on TeamCity to do this?

For example on each commit, I would like to run a smaller test suite, and then nightly it should run a full regress test suite. I'm not entirely sure how to set this up

Answer (score 1):

You have to add two different build configurations then specify the trigger based on a schedule for your night-time configuration and VCS-trigger for 'smaller test suite'. 
 Of course you could add time checking in your build script within one configuration and perform the actions depending on the condition, but it is not good way to solve this task.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you are wanting to do two different builds. This is a very common pattern that I've done for pretty much every project I've ever been involved with.

The pattern I use is to set up two different builds in TeamCity

First is a Continuous Integration build that will build the solution and run a subset of the unit tests filtered by some sort of attribute or flag on the test. For MsTest and C# this would be the TestCategoryAttribute. This build is set to run whenever someone checks in code and is designed to be quick to run and give you a quick way to see if anything obvious has broken.

The second build is a nightly build which is much more involved and can run for hours if need be as it is scheduled for late at night when everyone has gone home. This build will build the solution, run ALL the unit tests including the ones not run in the CI build, and package the solution if all is good. This build also does things like increment revision numbers and such.

So is there a way to run different build steps using build triggers? Not that I've found. But that isn't what I'd call common or best practice. Set up two distinct builds for two distinct aims. In TeamCity you can share the common stuff like VCS roots between build definitions real easy.

Answer (score 1):

Create a build configuration which does everything including the nightly tests. Under edit configuration select 'Extract Template'. Create a new configuration based on this template and disable the slow running tests. Each configuration can have its own triggers, but you don't have the maintenance overhead of two configurations with the same steps. You have two separate configurations, but they share the build steps and the only difference is the triggers and which steps are enabled.